# Views: how can I cleanly add a row of arbitrary text within a collection of fields?

Tags: views

I have a view that displays fields.  I want to add a text-based explanation as one of the rows in the view.  The display looks like this:

- Field A (Picture)
- Text 1: A row that contains explanatory text that appears regardless of whether there is any data below or not
- Field B (Data- may or may not be present)
- Field C (Data- may or may not be present)
- Field D (Data- may or may not be present)
- Field E (Data- may or may not be present)

What I'm currently doing to implement Text 1 is adding a field that will definitely always be available (user ID, etc.) and rewriting it to show the text I want to display.  This does what I want but it feels like an ugly hack.  Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Fields, select Global from the Group Dropdown and then you can select Custom Text and set it up pretty much anyway you'd like; at least in Drupal 6 and Views 3 anyway.

Comment: Thanks.  I knew there had to be a better way, and somehow I overlooked Custom Text.  This always works for D7 on Views 3.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a template file to theme the view. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2153347/how-to-theme-a-view-in-drupal) is a brief explanation.